# Is there a function in Excel to select every n-th cell in a column?

Tags: excel

I have a column of values in Excel, and I want to select only every 4th value, so for example cells A4, A8, A12, A16, etc, is there a formula to do this?

I've tried making a separate column of numbers that have my values, so a column with values 4, 8, 12, 16, etc, but I don't know how to tell Excel that I want the cell in column A with the row number specified in (for example) cell B52.

Comment: And do what with them?  Do you want to sum,average,....?

Comment: No I just want to put them in a separate column. So the original column would have A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6, ... and my new column would have values from A1, A4, A8 (in B1, B2, B3...)

Comment: A1,A4,A8 is not really the correct sequence I assume? Every 4th cell you said right?

Comment: Yes, every 4th cell, sorry about that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in B1:

```
=INDEX(A:A,ROW(A1)*4)
```

And copy down.

[image]

---

Once Microsoft releases the new formula to Office 365 we can make it dynamic:

```
=INDEX(A:A,SEQUENCE(INT(MATCH("zzz",A:A)/4),,4,4))
```

One would only need to put that in B1 and the rest would get filled in.

[image]